# saving new entity with relationships to two existing entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

In a spring mvc application using hibernate, I am encountering an error when I try to save a new object of one entity type which is associated with existing objects of two other entity types.  I have read many other postings about the given error message, but none of those postings seem to solve my specific problem.

I am trying to save a new object of type `Encounter`, which is associated with a specific existing `Provider` object and a specific existing `FacilityAddress` object.

Here is the error message that is given when the JSP's controller method starts calling its own methods:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:  
org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Provider
```

Here is the code for the `controller` methods that handle the action sent by the user from the JSP:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationForm(@PathVariable("patientId") int patientId, @RequestParam("providerId") int prid, org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest webRequest, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Encounter encounter = new Encounter();

    Map<Integer, String> praddrs = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>(); 
    for(FacilityAddress adr: this.clinicService.findFacilityAddressByProviderId(prid)){ 
        praddrs.put(adr.getId(), adr.getAddress());
    }

    Provider pr = clinicService.findProviderById(prid);
    model.put("encounter", encounter);
    model.put("praddrs", praddrs);
    model.put("pr", pr);
    return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";
}

//THIS IS THE METHOD THAT HANDLES THE FORM
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/new", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
public String processCreationForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter, @RequestParam("providerId") int providerId, @PathVariable("patientId") int patientId, org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest webRequest, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    System.out.println("inside processCreationForm() ");
    Patient patient = this.clinicService.findPatientById(patientId);
    LocalDate theday = new LocalDate(webRequest.getParameter("day"));
    LocalTime thetime = new LocalTime(webRequest.getParameter("time"));
    DateTime thedatetime = theday.toDateTime(thetime);
    encounter.setDateTime(thedatetime);
    patient.addEncounter(encounter);

    System.out.println("encounter.getDateTime() is: "+encounter.getDateTime());
    new EncounterValidator().validate(encounter, result);
    Provider myprovider = this.clinicService.findProviderById(providerId);
    encounter.addProvider(myprovider);
    myprovider.addEncounter(encounter);

    System.out.println(" jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj id, DateTime, getLocationSelected(), getNumMins(), Patient(), Status(), Providers().size() are: "+encounter.getId()+", "+encounter.getDateTime()+", "+encounter.getLocationSelected()+", "+encounter.getNumMins()+", "+encounter.getPatient().getFirstName()+", "+encounter.getStatus()+", "+encounter.getProviders().size());
    encounter.setLocation(this.clinicService.findFacilityAddressById(encounter.getLocationSelected()));
    System.out.println("done validating encounter for errors");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("about to return errors. ");
        return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";
    } else {
        System.out.println("about to save encounter ");
        this.clinicService.saveEncounter(encounter);
        System.out.println("done saving encounter.");
        status.setComplete();
        System.out.println("finished status.setComplete()");
        return "redirect:/encounters?encounterID={encounterId}";
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the `EncounterRepository` that is ultimately called by the code above, see that

```
@Override
public void save(Encounter encounter) {
    if (encounter.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("about to persist encounter.");
        this.em.persist(encounter);
        System.out.println("done persisting encounter");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("about to merge encounter.");
        this.em.merge(encounter);
        System.out.println("done merging encounter.");
    }
}
```

To keep this posting concise, I have uploaded the code for the entities to a file sharing site which you can access by clicking on the following links below:

The code for the `Encounter` entity can be found [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/GzFP4aLwsrqiOFI1muHs?b=xFW9WyRDoGy3mv7s0qBg).
The code for the `Provider` entity can be found [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/2tnPFWHHsoTC3PDMtJQj?b=lzoutFhUX4LRgUeNhWlH).
The code for the `FacilityAddress` entity can be found [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/X2af8wwueVhXKp15IxRC?b=1xknI9BpUnlgBbmGwIhf).

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Provider; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Provider
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:668) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.util.CallMonitoringAspect.invoke(CallMonitoringAspect.java:80) ~[CallMonitoringAspect.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy45.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.service.ClinicServiceImpl.saveEncounter(ClinicServiceImpl.java:204) ~[ClinicServiceImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy48.saveEncounter(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.web.EncounterController.processCreationForm(EncounterController.java:115) ~[EncounterController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73) [datatables-core-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71) [datatables-servlet2-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_29]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Provider
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:843) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:836) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:53) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:388) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:418) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:853) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:831) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy37.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.repository.jpa.JpaEncounterRepositoryImpl.save(JpaEncounterRepositoryImpl.java:101) ~[JpaEncounterRepositoryImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Just a tip... Use a debugger to pinpoint problems instead of polluting your code with `System.out.println` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally occurs with hibernate lazy initialisation. There are two solutions, first and the best is using OpenSessionInViewFilter for hibernate. The other one is using eager initialisation in your hbm file.

Define OpenSessionInViewFilter in projects `web.xml` at the top of your filter chain. Documentation is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html).

Comment: The `Encounter` and `Provider` entities both designate FetchType.EAGER for their relationship with each other in the entity files to which I linked in my original posting above.  The code this seems to already do what you are suggesting.  Are you willing to look at the code I posted above and make a specific suggestion based on it?  I have already read many postings and documents about the error message.  This question is about the specific code that I posted above.

Comment: `id`s are created when you persist. `ManyToMany` relations built on that id. Can you try to persist the `Encounter` object, then `encounter.addProvider(myprovider); myprovider.addEncounter(encounter);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the provider instance has been loaded in a separate transaction and is a detached object when being passed to the `save` method. Calling `em.persist()` tries to persist the provider object because of `CascadeType.ALL` setting and it throws the exception. Please note that all the load and save operations should be within the same transaction so the solution would be passing `providerId` and `facilityAddressId` to the service (`saveEncounter` in this case) and reloading them then setting those attached objects to the `encounter` and then saving `encounter`.